# How to Create Captcha Using Java?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, captcha

Actually in my Application have requirement like Enter Captcha word in the text box and validate that Captcha...

I'm Searching in Google so many things...but these are not understandable..

So please help me How to Create Captcha in java? using javascript or jquery or whatever easy technology in java related

Please Suggest me...

Comment: you want to 'create' captcha? or just want to use it on your page?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can use [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Comment: Yes i want to use my page but is it free?

Comment: @NarasimhamK - did you READ the linked page before you asked that???

Comment: why these guys are giving -1 for my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jcaptcha and the setup is very simple

By adding a small form code and a servlet mapping will do the trick.

```
<form action="submit.action">
...
    <img src="jcaptcha.jpg" /> <input type="text" name="jcaptcha" value="" />
...
</form>
```

[SetUp](https://jcaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/display/general/Simple+Servlet+Integration+documentation)

Comment: @Baadshah.. Thankyou. But i'm using In Spring DispatcherServlet so.. any problem on this..

Comment: IMO no problems.Captcha maintains its own servlet mapping for refresh the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to **use** Captcha, you can use [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) for free on your site. To know more how to use it with Java, check [this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java).